# Applying styles in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

I have tried to apply styles (stroke,fill..) in a vector layers(kml,geojson) but I never see changes in the map. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">

<style>

.map {
    height: 510px;
    width: 100%;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="map" class="map">
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript">

_myStroke = new ol.style.Stroke({
     color : 'rgba(255,0,0,1.0)',
     width : 1    
});

_myFill = new ol.style.Fill({
     color: 'rgba(255,0,0,1.0)'
});

myStyle = new ol.style.Style({
     stroke : _myStroke,
     fill : _myFill
 });


var raster1 = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.Stamen({
      layer: 'toner-lite'
      })
});

var isocrona = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
          url: './datos/isocronas_json.geojson',
          format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
          extractStyles: false,
          style: myStyle
          })
      });

var map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [raster1, isocrona],
      view: new ol.View({
          projection: 'EPSG:4326',
          center: [-4.4328, 36.7277],
          zoom: 12

          }),

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The style goes on the layer not the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var isocrona = new ol.layer.Vector({
    style: myStyle,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: './datos/isocronas_json.geojson',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        extractStyles: false,
    })
});
```

Or better yet, now you can produce a custom style based on the feature and resolution:

```
var isocrona = new ol.layer.Vector({
    style: (feature, resolution) => myStyle,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: './datos/isocronas_json.geojson',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        extractStyles: false,
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time ca0v. Only the second answer worked (style: (feature, resolution) => myStyle). Do you know where i can get information about the styles? i saw the openlayersbook but the examples are very simple

Comment: Other question: why this code works: style: (feature, resolution) => myStyle?  and this not: var isocrona = style: myStyle ? Thanks

Comment: Both should have worked.  Take a look at the docs and notice the link to the source code in the right-most column of the docs.  That's how I figure out the details I'm not picking up on from the docs alone.
http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html

Comment: I'd refer you to the docs again for styling but I've build a strange tool that might help give you idea of what is possible.
https://rawgit.com/ca0v/ol3-lab/v3.20.1/rawgit.html?run=ol3-lab/labs/style-lab&debug=1

Answer (score 0):

This link should help you out! I am a beginner with OpenLayers as well, but these sample codes tend to help me out. (Chapter 6)

http://openlayersbook.github.io/ch06-styling-vector-layers/intro.html

Comment: Please summarize the main concept here, otherwise this answer might turn useless when the links break.

Comment: Yes, i saw the openlayers book and i have tried the examples but there is no changes in the map.